# Selenium Webdriver: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting error as below :-

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with xpath == //*[@id='userId']

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="_ssoUser" id="userId" class="inforTextbox required" data-localizedtext="placeholder:UserID" aria-required="true" placeholder="User Name">
```

I have tried all below options, nothing is working.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='userId']"))); 

WebElement userid = driver.findElement(By.name("_ssoUser")); 
WebElement userid =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userId']"));
WebElement userid = driver.findElement(By.id("userId"));

driver.switchTo().frame(1);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("_ssoUser")));
```

Comment: Have you tried WebElement userid =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='userId']"));

Comment: if your frame is present before above HTML code then you need to switch first. is your id or name is unique on DOM

Comment: I am not sure where to find the frame in HTML. Also i couldn't find any Frame id or Frame name. Just to try i also used driver.switchTo().frame(0) and driver.switchTo().frame(1), still not working.

Comment: I think the element is present after the Frame but i couldn't find any Frame id or Frame name.

Comment: Guys its working now. I just found out the frame name is "content" and i used driver.switchTo().frame("content"). Thanks for all your help !!

Comment: Please do not roll back good edits to questions. As you can see in this case, someone reapplied one of my edits that you rolled back (putting in the error in a quote block) so it is their time you have wasted. In general, new users should accept edits to their questions unless they are sure the new edit is wrong, or it substantively changes the meaning of the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below xpath

```
//input[@id='userId' and @name='_ssoUser' and @placeholder='User Name']
```

If your above element is present after frame then you need to switch first and then look for the element

Another thing is you can switch to frame by frame xpath,name or frame id also. Try that too

You can check first weather your element is present or not in your HTML DOM to prevent from error/failer of script. like below:-

```
  if (driver.findElements("YOUR LOCATOR").size() != 0) {  
            driver.findElement(YOUR LOCATOR).click();  
            System.out.println("element exists");     
        }  
  else{
           System.out.println("element is not exists");     
      }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help first. Still its not working. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //input[@id='userId' and @name='_ssoUser' and @placeholder='User Name'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 457 milliseconds

Comment: I think the element is present after the Frame but i couldn't find any Frame id or Frame name. Just to try i also used driver.switchTo().frame(0) and driver.switchTo().frame(1), still not working.

Comment: its working now. I just found out the frame name is "content" and i used driver.switchTo().frame("content"). Thanks for your help !!